# Google Youtube API v3 (using public API key) is working as intended on localhost web app, but not on live sever

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My web application is supposed to fetch a YouTube video and display it to the user. The application works fine on localhost but when I made the web app live using AWS server, it is not working.

I have created public API key in https://console.developers.google.com. My application is written in PHP.

I am quiet new to the world of coding and this thing has started to give me nightmares as I have tried everything and read all the similar reported issues on stackoverflow, but of no avail.

Please help me!

Here goes my codes. (Please pardon me for inefficiently written codes, considering am very new to this coding world):

```
if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])){

$username = $userLoggedInObj->getUsername();


$API_Key = '...';

$BaseYoutubeURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?';

$videoURL = $_POST["youtubeURL"];

$youtubeVideoId = substr($videoURL, -11, 50);

$API_URL = $BaseYoutubeURL . "part=snippet&id=" . $youtubeVideoId . "&key=" . $API_Key;

$videoData = json_decode(file_get_contents($API_URL));
    
    $title = $videoData->items[0]->snippet->title;
    $description = $videoData->items[0]->snippet->description;
    $channelTitle = $videoData->items[0]->snippet->channelTitle;
    $publishedDate = $videoData->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;
    $thumbnailURL = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $youtubeVideoId . '/mqdefault.jpg';

    $view_API_URL = $BaseYoutubeURL . "part=statistics&id=" . $youtubeVideoId . "&key=" . $API_Key;
    $viewData = json_decode(file_get_contents($view_API_URL));

    $viewCount = $viewData->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

    $YoutubeVideoData = new YoutubeVideoDataProcessor();
    $duration = $YoutubeVideoData->getYoutubeDuration($youtubeVideoId);


 $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO curatedVideos (username, youtube_Video_URL, youtube_Video_Id, title, description, thumbnail_URL, channel_Title, views, published_Date, duration)VALUES(:username, :videoURL, :videoId, :title, :description, :thumbnailURL,:channelTitle, :views, :publishedDate, :duration)");

    $query->bindParam(":username", $username);
    $query->bindParam(":videoURL", $videoURL);
    $query->bindParam(":videoId", $youtubeVideoId);
    $query->bindParam(":title", $title);
    $query->bindParam(":description", $description);
    $query->bindParam(":thumbnailURL", $thumbnailURL);
    $query->bindParam(":channelTitle", $channelTitle);
    $query->bindParam(":views", $viewCount);
    $query->bindParam(":publishedDate", $publishedDate);
    $query->bindParam(":duration", $duration);

    $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take your time to absorb [the info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) SO recommends new users to be acquainted with. Afterwards, edit your post, adding to it relevant missing information (without which the other SO users cannot come to your help).

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: added the codes

Comment: Hi @Hermant, avoid to post API Keys next time, its for your use only. stvar already edited your post, so you good now.

Comment: Do note that for `file_get_contents` to accept URLs, you have to have enabled [`fopen wrappers`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-get-contents-notes). I suspect that on the AWS server, [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) may well be disabled by default.

Comment: I have enabled fopen_wrappers. It didn't work.

Comment: @HemantRoshan does your api key has any restrictions? - check the console of your browser: Example: press F12 key and check the "Console" tabl - and then check if there are errors. if you get errors in the console, please add it in your question by pression the [edit] link.